# How can I add a launcher for a shell file to Gnome favorites?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

A program I regularly use is based on Java and started with a shell file. I would like to add a launcher for this program/shell file to the favorites menu of my Gnome desktop on Ubuntu 15.10.

How can I do that?

Comment: There is a very nice article about how to do this at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example. Not as comprehensive as Charles's link though - http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/install-light-table-ide-create-launcher-ubuntu/

`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel --no-install-recommends`
`sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new`

NOTE: Example below uses /opt/Appname as the app directory

**Name:** Appname
**command:** /opt/Appname/Appname
**choose icon** example /opt/Appname/core/img/lticon.png